# 404 error on post request in ec2 server

Tags: api, amazon-ec2, http-post, http-status-code-404

I deployed my mean stack project to amazon ec2 instance and i tried to login and it returns me 404 error (Cannot POST /api/user/login). Both the client side and server side code is inside the same project. When i run the project from localhost it works fine. What could be the issue ? Thanks.

Edit : Code snipped added

From controller

```
var credentials = {
            email : $scope.user.email,
            password : $scope.user.password
        };


        User.login(credentials)
            .then(function (response) {

                // Administrator. Redirect to /admin.html page
                if($cookies.get('userType') == 0) { 
                    $location.path('/admin');
                }

                console.log("From controller "+ response);

            })
            .catch(function(error) {
                console.log(error);
            })
```

From service

```
            $http({
                method : 'POST',
                url : '/api/user/login',
                data : data
            })
            .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                object = JSON.parse(Util.toObject(data));console.log(object._id);
                $cookies.put('userType', object['status']); // 0 for admin
                $cookies.put('email', object.email); // store the email for session.
                console.log(object['status']  + ' ' +  object.email);
                $('#loginModal').hide();
                deffered.resolve(Util.toObject(data));
            })
            .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log("Error in Login "+ status);
                deffered.reject(data);
            })
```

BE route

```
app.use('/api/admin', require('./admin'));
```

Inside admin folder, index.js file

```
router.post('/login', controller.login);
```

controller.login file

```
exports.login = function(req, res) {
console.log(req.body);
User.find(req.body, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(' Error in finding the data .. ');
    }
    else {
        console.log(' Data found in login ' + JSON.stringify(data));
        res.status(200).json(data);
    }
});
};
```

Comment: You're going to have to give a lot more details about this one. Since you're getting a `404`, sounds like your server is running, but it doesn't find your endpoint. Are you sure your application is being hosted and served correctly?

Comment: @birryree This is the error i'm getting. POST http://ec2-52-88-27-247.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:9000/api/user/login 404 (Not Found)(anonymous function) Error in Login 404
controllers.js:30 Cannot POST /api/user/login

Comment: @birryree I cloned the project from bitbucket and installed right packages. Did i miss any configuration ?

Comment: What project is this? Without any details about what you're running and what the code looks like for the controller, I can't really help any further.

Comment: @birryree Added code snippet. Please check

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue in the end. I added '/' at the end of each API endpoint and it worked.